# calculating the limit $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}((4^n+3)^{1/n}-(3^n+4)^{1/n})^{n3^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

We need to calculating the limit 
$$
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}((4^n+3)^{1/n}-(3^n+4)^{1/n})^{n3^n}
$$

I have tried taking the logarithm, but the limit doesnt seem to arrive at any familiar form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the limit should be $e^{-12}$.

First, after you rewrite the expression within the brackets, you get 
$$
4(1+\frac{3}{4^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} - 3(1+\frac{4}{3^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
Both expressions within the two brackets can be expanded using Generalized binomial theorem, and the leading terms will be 
$$
4(1+\frac{3}{n 4^n}) - 3(1+\frac{4}{n 3^n}) + o(1) = 1+ \frac{4}{n 3^n} + O\Big(\frac{1}{n4^n}\Big)  
$$

so the limit becomes 
$$
\bigg(1 - \frac{12}{n 3^n} \bigg)^{n 3^n} \to_n e^{-12}
$$

EDIT:

because $O\Big(\frac{1}{n4^n}\Big)$ doesn't affect the convergence rate. To see that, consider
\begin{align}
\Big(1+\frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{n^2} \Big)^n 
&= \Big(\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{n+1}{n}}\Big)\Big)^n\\
&= \Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n\Big(1+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} +o(1)\Big)\\
& = \Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n\Big(1+o(1)\Big) \to_n e
\end{align}

Comment: I'm geting $1-12/(n3^{n}) + o(1/(n3^{n}))$ inside the parentheses, giving the limit of $e^{-12}.$ Note also that $o(1)$ is not nearly good enough here.

Comment: Absolutely right about $-12$ term. I think the next order term should be $\frac{12}{n4^n}$, which is $o (\frac{1}{n 3^n})$, so the limit should hold

Comment: But leaving just $o(1)$ in your sketch is misleading I think.

Comment: @zhw: fixed. also added an edit on convergence

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint by [Alex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2791877/505767) with some more detail, we have that

- $(4^n+3)^{1/n}=4\left(1+\frac3{4^n}\right)^\frac1n=4e^{\frac1n\log \left(1+\frac3{4^n}\right)}=4\left(1+\frac3{n4^n}+o\left(\frac1{n4^n}\right)\right)=\\=4+\frac{12}{n4^n}+o\left(\frac{12}{n4^{n}}\right)$
- $(3^n+4)^{1/n}=3\left(1+\frac4{3^n}\right)^\frac1n=3e^{\frac1n\log \left(1+\frac4{3^n}\right)}=3\left(1+\frac4{n3^n}+o\left(\frac1{n3^n}\right)\right)=\\=3+\frac{12}{n3^n}+o\left(\frac{12}{n3^{n}}\right)$

then

$$( (4^n+3)^{1/n}-(3^n+4)^{1/n} )^{n3^n}=\left(1-\frac{12}{n3^n}+o\left(\frac{12}{n3^{n}}\right)\right)^{n3^n}=$$

$$=\left[\left(1-\frac{12}{n3^n}+o\left(\frac{12}{n3^{n}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{-\frac{12}{n3^n}+o\left(\frac{12}{n3^{n}}\right)}}\right]^{-12+o(1)}\to e^{-12}$$

Comment: How do you get the first line? For a fixed $p$ we have by Taylor that $(1+x)^p = 1 +px + o(x).$ But that $o(x)$ term depends on $p$ as well. In this problem we have something of the form $(1+x_n)^{p_n}.$ Why is that $1+p_nx_n+o(x_n),$ where $o(x_n)$ is independent of $p_n?$ (I know how to do this, but I think it's worth mentioning.)

Comment: @zhw. We can use $$\left(1+\frac3{4^n}\right)^\frac1n=e^{\frac1n\log \left(1+\frac3{4^n}\right)}$$ and then use $\log$ and $exp$ expansion.